# Assignment position

Tags: python, variable-assignment, assign

I made 4 print statements and I got 1 different answer from the rest. Could somebody explain that "0" answer please.
Also, if "product = 1" is put above "for i in" then the loops only goes 1 time which I also don't understand.

```
s = "73167176531330624919225119674426..." # 1000 digit number

largestProduct = 0
for i in range(0, len(s) - 13):

    product = 1

    for j in range(i, i + 13):
        product *= int(s[j])

    if product > largestProduct:
        largestProduct = product
        print(product)
        print(largestProduct)

print(product)
print(largestProduct)

>> answers
23514624000
23514624000
0
23514624000
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your code does not allow for reproduction of the problem. Please make sure to provive an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when submitting a question.

Comment: what are you trying to acheive?

Answer (score 1):

About your first question **(1) Why is it printing a zero for product after the look?**

You didn't print the full string `s` but I assume you have in the last 13 digits at least one zero. If there is one zero it will result in the whole product being zero.

**(2) Why does it only run once if product is above the first for loop?**
Here two things come together:
- The product gets only initialized once with one, so all the next number are multiplied with the last result
- You have a zero at `14`, so after executing it once, the product will be multiplied by zero and you will end up with a result of zero which will never be bigger than the `largestProduct`

For example, in your first iteration `product = 1`and after multiplying them it is `5000940`, this is bigger than `largestProduct`so it is written to the command line. Next the last digit is a zero, and product is not set to 1 again but keeps the previous value, after multiplying the zero with it, product is zero, and no matter what number comes next it will stay zero.